# how to pass variable from html to ajax/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have below HTML page which I land on after successful authentication. In its body, I get access_token value.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Authorization successful</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Welcome. You are authorized to access the page.</p>     
    <p>access_token: {{ access_token }}</p>
    <p>token_type:   {{ token_type }}</p>
    
    <form method="POST" action="/protected_hi" >                   
        <button type="submit" id="protectedApiButton">Protected API</button>
    </form>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The page has a button named "Protected API" on which ajax.js script it registers.
How can I get the access_token variable's value in my ajax.js script?

```
let protectedApiButton = document.getElementById('protectedApiButton');
protectedApiButton.addEventListener('click', buttonClickHandler)

function buttonClickHandler() {
    
    var myAttribute = <------------- how to assign access_token value from html template to here?
    console.log(myAttribute);

    
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');


    
    xhr.onprogress = function(){
        console.log('On progress');
    }

    
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if(this.status === 200){

            console.log(this.responseText)
        }
        else{
            console.log("Some error occurred")
        }
    }   
    params = `{"name":"ravi","age":"43"}`;          
    xhr.send(params);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the input with the type of hidden to store the access token.

```
<input type="hidden" id="access_token" value="token-goes-here" />
```

Then retrieve the value from `access_token` in the `buttonClickHandler()`:

```
function buttonClickHandler() {
  var myAttribute = document.getElementById('access_token').value;
  ...
}
```